# Backbone variables versus page containers . . .?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

So I have inherited a bit of backbone.js code and need to make a change to it today. The guy who wrote the original code is on vacation. I am just barely studying up on backbone.js and am pretty much a backbone newbie.

**The code below works and does what it was designed for.** There is only one issue: The contents of the template file (see below) get rendered into a specific HTML page.

**My problem is that I don't fully understand the flow of the code** to make an educated guess as far as how and where to insert a reference to an actual container on that HTML page, and get the content to display inside that container.

The class name of the container where I need the output from this function to go is `.mngmnt-main-sctn`. Is this possible to do?

.

```
window.ManagementInstancesBackupView = ManagementView.extend({

  events: _.extend({
    }, ManagementView.prototype.events
  ),

  initialize: function() {
    this.model      = this.options.model
    this.collection = this.options.collection
    this.template   = _.template($('#instances-management-backup-template').html())
  },

  render: function() {
    var instances = this.collection

   // Append container and title
   var $el = this.$el.html(this.template({}))

   instances.each(function(instance) {

    //    THIS IS THE CONTAINER THAT SHOULD GET STUFF APPENDED TO:
    //    $(".mngmnt-main-sctn")


      $el.append(this.renderParent(instance));

      instance.get('nic').each(function(nic) {
        $el.append(this.renderChild(nic));
      }, this)
    }, this)

    return this
  },

  renderParent: function(instance) {
    return new ManagementInstancesBackupParentView({model: instance}).render().$el
  },

  renderChild: function(nic) {
    return new ManagementInstancesBackupChildView({model: nic}).render().$el
  }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are asking is possible like this.

```
window.ManagementInstancesBackupView = ManagementView.extend({

  el: ".mngmnt-main-sctn"

  [...code excluded...]

});
```

We are overriding the el property meaning that when this line is called

```
var $el = this.$el.html(this.template({}))
```

this.$el will refer to the element you have specified.

Comment: Jacob – Thanks a lot for taking the time. Unfortunately, with that additional code, nothing happens at all. All this stuff gets trigeered when I click a button, which brings up a new view with the output from that code. Now I get nothing. There is not even anything captured in the console log.

Comment: OK. This is probably because some events are attached from the original element which we have now overridden. Can you post the code for "ManagementView" which you current code extends.

Answer (score 0):

Jacob, thanks again for looking into this.

I found a solution and now I'm definitely going to hit additional backbonejs tutorials. Within the code, I was able to add the selector like so:

```
  // Append container and title
  var $el = this.$el.html(this.template({})).find('.mngmnt-main-sctn')
```

.
I'm always perplexed by stuff like this. You can't find any answers to solve the problem, then you try a 1,000 different things . . . and then the solution seems so simple and I always feel a bit foolish after such an experience.